# Lazarus RandomRange function

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

I have a problem with RandomRange, this is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
i : Integer;

  function RandomRange(const AFrom, ATo: Integer): Integer;
  begin
  Result := RandomRange(15,20);
  Case Result of
  15 : ShowMessage('message1');
  16 : ShowMessage('message2');
  17 : ShowMessage('message3');
  18 : ShowMessage('message4');
  19 : ShowMessage('message5');
  20 : ShowMessage('message6');
  end;
end.
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
unit1.pas(46,30) Hint: Parameter "AFrom" not used
unit1.pas(46,37) Hint: Parameter "ATo" not used
unit1.pas(57,4) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "." found
```

What could it be? thanks

Comment: What makes you think it's anything besides *exactly what the compiler told you* it is?

Answer (score 2):

You have  a couple of errors in your code.

The major one  is that your final `end` is followed by a `.` instead of a `;`. `end.` means the end of the unit, but you haven't terminated the method block for `function RandomRange` or the event handler `TForm1.FormCreate` yet.

The two warnings are because you're not using the parameters. :-) You declare the `AFrom` and `ATwo` parameters to the outer `RandomRange` function, but never use them in the code. It's getting confused by the inner call to `RandomRange`, which is confusing the  compiler as to scope.

I'd change it to something like:

```
function MyRandomRange: Integer;
begin
  Result := RandomRange(15, 20);
  case Result of
    15 : ShowMessage('message1');
    16 : ShowMessage('message2');
    17 : ShowMessage('message3');
    18 : ShowMessage('message4');
    19 : ShowMessage('message5');
    20 : ShowMessage('message6');
  end;
end;
```

If the compiler complains about not being able to find `RandomRange`, you're probably missing a unit in your `uses` clause. In Delphi, `RandomRange` is defined in the `math` unit; it's probably in the same unit in Free Pascal.

If you want to keep it embedded as a local function like your original code, it would be something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  function MyRandomRange: Integer;
  begin
    Result := RandomRange(15, 20);
    case Result of
      15 : ShowMessage('message1');
      16 : ShowMessage('message2');
      17 : ShowMessage('message3');
      18 : ShowMessage('message4');
      19 : ShowMessage('message5');
      20 : ShowMessage('message6');
    end;
  end;
begin
  MyRandomRange;
end;
```

Comment: unit1.pas(52,24) Error: Identifier not found "RandomRange"
unit1.pas(64,1) Fatal: Syntax error, "BEGIN" expected but "END" found

Comment: See my edit (last paragraph added to my answer).

Comment: Thanks, it's now okay, but I still have an error: unit1.pas(67,1) Fatal: Syntax error, "BEGIN" expected but "END" found

Comment: @GiacomoKingPatermo because you have 2 "end" and only one "begin"

Comment: Serves to close the function, however, I resolved.

Comment: You can also use the same name for the func but you have to specify the unitname: <unitname>.RandomRage(15,20);